# Communicating with an USB device over “USB Virtual Serial Port” using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port, usb, mbed

I recently plugged in an USB embedded device(mbed lpc1768) using a normal USB cable to a Windows 7 desktop.  According to the docs that came with the program running on the device it communicates with the host(desktop) over a USB Virtual Serial Port.

Where do I start if I need to read/write data using c#?   Could I use the SerialPort .NET class or do I need to use the LibUsbDotNet library or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is excellent news when I find out that a USB device communicates in VCP rather than USB-HID, because serial connections are easy to understand.

If the device is operating in `VCP` (Virtual Com Port), then it is as easy as using the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` type. You will need to know some basic information about the device, most of which can be gleaned from Windows Management (Device Manager). After constructing like so:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portNo, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
```

You [may or may not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957337/what-is-the-difference-between-dtr-dsr-and-rts-cts-flow-control) need to set some additional flags, such as *Request to send* (RTS) and *Data Terminal Ready* (DTR)

```
port.RtsEnable = true;
port.DtrEnable = true;
```

Then, open the port.

`port.Open();`

To listen, you can attach an event handler to `port.DataReceived` and then use `port.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`

```
port.DataReceived += (sender, e) => 
{ 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
    port.Read(buffer,0,port.BytesToRead);
    // Do something with buffer
};
```

To send, you can use `port.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`

Comment: Where do I see the portNo (port name)?  SerialPort.GetPortNames returns 0 ports.

Comment: In my case, I don't know the port number because it may not always be the same. I use a `ManagementObjectSearcher` to find the device (since I know the name), so I do `var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_SERIALPORT")` and iterate over the `ManagementBaseObject` collection in `searcher.Get()`. I'll work it into the answer.

Comment: Well it seems I needed to install a Mbed serial port driver for Windows(http://mbed.org/handbook/Windows-serial-configuration).  I ran it and the computer huffed and puffed for a few minutes, finally producing a nice "mbed serial port (COM3)" line in the Device manager!  :)  I'll try that.

Comment: Well if that's the case, for now, you can lazy hard-code the `PortNo` to `"COM3"`

Comment: RtsEnable and DtrEnable were required in my case. +1

Comment: Yes, RTS & DTR enable fixed my issue too!