# Send and recive date by USB in C#

Tags: c#, usb

I'm writing an application in C# (Windows Forms) that will communicate with IRIS XM2110 device over USB port. I want to send and recive simple commands over USB, so I'm looking for the best way to do that. I know there is no "native" Classes to do that, so I need some help.
I heard about LibUsbDotNet library, but I don't know if I need such a big library to just send and recive simple commands.
I also was thinking about SerialPort Class, but is it possible to communicate with USB by this Class?

Comment: from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554229/communicating-with-an-usb-device-over-usb-virtual-serial-port-using-c) seems you can use SerialPort class.

Comment: Fortunately I found that to communicate with computer I will use MIB520 device, that use Virtual Com Port, so it's simplifying my problem so much :)