# Arduino and C# Serial Port "Crash"

Tags: c#, multithreading, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to create a communication between an Arduino Leonardo and C#.

Just now, the Arduino's software sends a simple message (in loop) on the serial port:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(500);
}
```

C# try only to read these messages and print them on the shell:

```
public class Program
{
    private SerialPort mySerialPort;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine("PORTS: " + String.Join(" ", p.getSerialPortsList())+ ", enter to start.");
        Console.Read();
        p.SerialRead("COM6");
    }

    public String[] getSerialPortsList()
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        return ports;
    }

    public void SerialRead(String com)
    {
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort(com, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");
        SerialRead sr = new SerialRead();
        Thread rs = new Thread(sr.StartRead);
        sr.SetMySerialPort(mySerialPort);
        rs.Start();
        while (!rs.IsAlive);
        Console.Read();
        sr.SetSuspendThread(true);
        rs.Join();
    }

}


public class SerialRead
{

    private Boolean suspendThread = false;
    SerialPort mySerialPort;

    public void StartRead()
    {
        mySerialPort.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        int i = 0;
        while (!suspendThread)
        { 
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + mySerialPort.ReadLine());
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    public void SetMySerialPort(SerialPort mysp){ mySerialPort = mysp; }
    public void SetSuspendThread(Boolean a){ suspendThread = a; }

}
```

The output of this C# software depends. If I use the serial monitor on the Arduino IDE, then I receive the string's stream correctly (one each 500ms).
Otherwise, the C# software freezes. Sometimes, I receive a couple of strings as we can see [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA4tL.jpg); but almost all time, the software does not give any string, as we can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06NBH.jpg). After that the software freezes (thus, if I press enter the shell does not response).

Can you suggest a solution in order to get a fluent flow of string, and -as a consequence- read each message sent by Arduino on the serial port?

I am using Window 10 x64 as OS and the COM6 (it is an USB 2.0).

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and I share it in order to help people with the same problem.
C# does not activate as default the [RTS and the DTR serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957337/what-is-the-difference-between-dtr-dsr-and-rts-cts-flow-control). 
Thus, adding

```
mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
```

after the serial port declaration, everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've been pulling my hair out trying to get powershell to read an Arduino and this was why! I just needed to set these two lines in Powerhsell and it all worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good example:
[Serial Port Polling and Data handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124132/serial-port-polling-and-data-handling)

The Serial Port got an event called [DataRecived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8), so you dont have to sleep your thread.
Something like this:

```
serialPort.DataReceived +=SerialPortDataReceived;


private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(serialPort.ReadLine());
}
```